# Undefined Index Error in PHP Displayed on Web Page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am getting following errors on my Webpage

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\CWH\index.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: gender in C:\xampp\htdocs\CWH\index.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: age in C:\xampp\htdocs\CWH\index.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\CWH\index.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: phone in C:\xampp\htdocs\CWH\index.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: other in C:\xampp\htdocs\CWH\index.php on line 19

Below is the corrosponding PHP code

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$other = $_POST['other'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `trip` (`name`, `age`, `gender`, `email`, `phone`, `other`, `dt`) 
VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$gender', '$email', '$phone', '$other', current_timestamp());";
```

Below is the html code

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Enter your Age">
        <input type="text" name="gender" id="gender" placeholder="Enter your gender">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
        <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone no.">
        <textarea name="other" id="other" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Enter any other 
        information here"> </textarea>
```

Can anyone please tell me why I am getting this error.

Comment: You should check that the array elements for the `$_POST` superglobal array are not empty to prevent this undefined index error.

Answer (score 1):

As i see, you're not checking if the form is submitted, which means the PHP-Code is executed every time the page loads, not only if the form was submitted.

So, if you open the page, the `$_POST` array is empty, so `name`, `gender`, ... are undefined.

To fix this, you can give your submit-button a name and check if this is inside the `$_POST` array in your PHP-Code.

For example, if your submit button has this name `<input type="submit" value="Send" name="send">`, put your PHP-Code inside this if-statement:

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])) {
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   ...
}
```

If you want to completly remove warnings like this, check this for every single variable in the array with `isset($_POST["name"])` for the name and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the submit action through a button. So button html code will be `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Update">` . add this html code before close the form tag.

Then update the PHP code as like below .

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone= $_POST['phone'];
$other = $_POST['other'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `trip` (`name`, `age`, `gender`, `email`, `phone`, `other`, `dt`) 
VALUES ('$name', '$age', '$gender', '$email', '$phone', '$other', current_timestamp());";
}`
```